# Cálculo de totales acumulados SQL procedimiento almacenados

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Quiero multiplicar las dos columnas Qty y Price cada fila y después tener una suma total en Columna Total. El primer proceso me funciona al insertar pero cuando quiero actualizar no funciona.

```
alter PROCEDURE spInsert_Inventory
    @Brand Varchar(50),
    @Series Varchar(50),
    @Model Varchar(50),
    @Ram int,
    @HDD int,
    @Qty int,
    @Price int) AS BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Laptops
        WHERE Brand=@Brand
            and Series=@Series
            and Model=@Model
            and ram=@Ram 
            and hdd=@HDD 
    )
    BEGIN
    declare @totale int=0
    set @totale=(@Price*@Qty)
    INSERT into Laptops Values (@Brand,@Series,@Model,@Ram,@HDD,@Qty,@Price,@totale)
    END
ELSE
 BEGIN
        UPDATE Laptops set qty=@Qty, Price=@Price,Total=Total+
        (select(sum(@Price*@Qty)))
        WHERE Brand=@Brand 
            and Series=@Series
            and Model=@Model 
            and ram=@Ram 
            and hdd=@HDD 
    END
END
```

Comment: puedes mostrar un ejemplo de los datos y el resultado que quieres?. Qué versión de SQL Server (según veo) estás usando?

Comment: select Brand,Series,Ram,HDD,Qty,Price, Total = Sum(Price*Qty) OVER (partition BY Brand)
from Laptops

Comment: Me refería a que postearas eso en la pregunta, no en un comentario (no hay formato, así que no se entiende bien)

Comment: La sentencia de `update` está mal construida. debiera ser `Total=Total+(@Price*@Qty)`  en todo caso.

Comment: Esto con Total=Total+(@Price*@Qty)+ en todo caso no me sale nada en Total. Lo cierto que la sentencia de update está mal construida!

Comment: Revisa que alguna de las dos variables no sea NULL ya que eso te invalida la suma.

Comment: Además, estás seguro que en la tabla, `Total` es distinto a NULL?

Comment: Para más seguridad puedes hacer esto `Total=isnull(Total,0)+(@Price*@Qty)` si estás seguro que estás  variables no son nulas.

Comment: con Total=isnull(Total,0)+(@Price*@Qty) me pone resultado doble. No se que estoy haciendo mal..Gracias por las respuestas